# How to prevent Jekyll-import (WordPress) from replacing double <br> HTML tags with a single <P> tag?

Tags: html, wordpress, import, jekyll

I have a WordPress blog that I'm trying to import into Jekyll using jekyll-import. While it basically works, it insists on replacing two BR tags («br /»«br /») with a «p» tag. This may make sense in general, but as these BR tags are inside a «pre» block, this completely breaks rendering (the «pre» block leaks).

Does anyone know how I prevent the importer from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import/blob/master/lib/jekyll-import/util.rb
maybe you want to nop this method for your import and manually clean up the markdown later.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I want to change. Where would I find this on my hard disk? I simply used "gem install", so I have no idea where it actually put the files :-S

Comment: Okay, found it: Do a `gem env` to log your environment. Under `GEM PATHS:` you'll see possible locations. I found it at the first, `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-import-0.5.3/lib/jekyll-import/util.rb`

Comment: Okay, found a solution: On line 17 of util.rb is a huge assignment statement that assigns various tag names to a variable named `allblocks` ("table|thead|tfoot" etc.). If I take out the entry for `pre` everything converts fine.

Comment: Drat. Seems that wasn't it. Turns out the bug wasn't in Jekyll-import, but actually in Jekyll's markdown-to-HTML converter converting the file back :-(